# JavaScript/CSS Infinite Zoom on A Symmetric Image

Tags: javascript, d3.js, css-animations, zooming, css-transitions

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65489356/2521204) fascinating. What is the most efficient way to do a similar thing on one single symmetric image, such as: [image 1](https://archello.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/2014/02/10/01-PRISM-DESIGN.1506072655.482.jpg) or [image 2](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/28/20/81/282081b54866ad092632aa4c48af92b7.jpg)

The ultimate goal is to let the user zoom infinitely using something like [d3-zoom](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom), but as they zoom in, the same image gets loaded seamlessly, such that the user feels the image has no end.

Comment: How do people come up with these things??... That's absolutely insane. And then there's me feeling proud for my html login page.